# How can i store file name and file path to the database in DataGridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i am trying to store file name and file path to the database by opening a OpenFileDiologue. here my codes.
NOTE: DB is already connected. properly showing data on datagridview and database is created with ms access named database1.accdb.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim showdialog1 As New OpenFileDialog

    showdialog1.Filter = "Supported Video Files. | *.mp4; *.avi; *.wmv; *.mpg; *.mpeg; *.mov; *.webm; *.flv; *.mkv"
    showdialog1.Title = "Add Supported Video Files."
    If showdialog1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = showdialog1.FileName

    Else

        Exit Sub

    End If
End Sub
```

here is a pic of my design. this will help you to understand me.
[Click to View the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiE5N.jpg) 
help me to store file name and file path to the database. hope i will get the easiest method.

Comment: Use a DataSource like a DataTable.  Add the path and name to that.  Your DB Providers can then update the DataBase very easily, and you can display the data in the DGV using that DataTable as a DataSource.

Comment: i am trying to store these text (file name, file path) to a database. help me to do it if u want. thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  But it is not clear what you are stuck on.  Your question touches on DataBases, FileDialogs and DGV - which makes it far too broad.  Do some research on the various topics, write some code and post when you have a specific question.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: If you're able to retrieve data from a database and display it in a `DataGridView` then hopefully you are using a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and binding that to the grid. If you're not then you should, so learn how to do that if you need to. Once that's done, saving any changes to that data is simply a case of calling `Update` on the same data adapter. All the other stuff is irrelevant. Getting data from a database into a `DataTable` and saving changes is the same regardless of what you do with that `DataTable`.

Comment: If your question is actually about how to get the file name and path into the grid in the first place then that has nothing to do with databases. As @Plutonix suggests, you need to break a problem up and deal with one part at a time.

Comment: Perhaps the following code sample will assist with what you are after. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MS-Access-working-with-00e96d88?redir=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple :

```
 Public sub Button1_Click
 'your connection string
 connection.open

 Dim cmd as new Oledbcommand("Insert into 
 [tablename](columnname) values (@mycolumn)",yourconnectionstringname)

 If openfiledialog1.dialogresult=dialogresult.ok then
 cmd.parametres.add("@mycolumn",sqldbtype.varchar).value=openfiledialog1.filename

 cmd.executenonquery()

 connection.close
```

I hope this would help to achieve your goal